Points of definitions of Composite Functions
If f(x) is not defined at x=a then is g(f(x)) defined at x=a?
For example, in this question
Let $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=\log_ex$. The number of values of $x$ for which $(fog)(x)=(gof)(x)$ is?
Would $fog (x)$ be defined at $x=0$?

It would not.
In looking at $(f \circ g)(x)$, i.e. $f(g(x))$, if $g(x_0)$ is not defined, then $f(g(x_0))$ isn't either, full stop.
After all, think about it: if you wanted to evaluate $f(g(0))$, you would need to:

plug $x=0$ into $g(x)$, hence finding $g(0)$
take that value and plug it into $f(x)$ for $x$

...but if $g(0)$ isn't defined, you can't find anything to plug in!

Thank you so much!
